# Unable to install package "dplyr" in R (Stuck while compiling)

Tags: compiling, r

I ran into the issue of R being stuck while installing packages.

```
-DBOOST_NO_INT64_T -DBOOST_NO_INTEGRAL_INT64_T -DBOOST_NO_LONG_LONG -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector >--param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c distinct.cpp -o distinct.o

g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR  -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -DBOOST_NO_INT64_T -DBOOST_NO_INTEGRAL_INT64_T -DBOOST_NO_LONG_LONG -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security >-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c dplyr.cpp -o dplyr.o

^C/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:141: recipe for target 'dplyr.o' failed
make: *** [dplyr.o] Interrupt
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/usr/lib/R/site-library/dplyr’

The downloaded source packages are in

‘/tmp/Rtmp72KGCW/downloaded_packages’


Warning message:


In install.packages("dplyr") :

  installation of package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status
```

How can I install packages with/for R?

*Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a cloud server*

Comment: *"stuck"* - it looks like you are Ctrl-C'ing out of the process? just be patient, the final build step appears to take a LOOONG time (not sure why)

Comment: @steeldriver I tried the same steps on two different VPSs I set up recently and looks like the other one went through the compiling no problem. Will give it another shot...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an AWS t2.micro instance, the problem is that it doesn't have enough memory. You can upgrade the instance type under actions in the EC2 Management Console.

Comment: Thanks, had the same problem and upgrading the instance helped.